# Need Help to fix this code to work with CrptoJs or OpenSSL commands

Tags: node.js, openssl, cryptojs

Hi Esteemed member of StackOverflow,
I have a closed environment where I cannot use node js or any other language apart from OpenSSL or CrptoJs version of this crypto-Js Module.

My code is working in Node Js and I have attached the working version here.
Can anyone of you help me in getting a working version in OpenSSL or in CrptoJs?

```
'use strict';
const crypto = require('crypto');

// The two keys gotten from Trustpilot
let encryptionKeyBase64 = 'JB+FsIQEMWjdhB/xLus/SpbaZje9wQQ785tECAsHzF4=';
let authenticationKeyBase64 = 'HFLYS943++xwKuj3qTypmB9F+pFzmNavccKJO+Mm2nY=';

// Our info to encrypt
let info = {
    "email":"xyz@domain.com",
    "name":"John Smith",
    "ref":"1234",
    "skus":["sku1","sku2","sku3"],
    "tags":["tag1","tag2","tag3"]
};
let jsonSerializedOrder = JSON.stringify(info);

// When you get the keys from Trustpilot, they are base64 encoded, so first we need to decode them
let encryptionKey = Buffer.from(encryptionKeyBase64, 'base64');
console.log('encryptionKey'+encryptionKey);
let authenticationKey = Buffer.from(authenticationKeyBase64, 'base64');
console.log('authenticationKey'+authenticationKey);
// Generate a random initialization vector
let iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
console.log('iv'+iv);
// Encrypt our order
let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', encryptionKey, iv);
console.log('cipher'+cipher);
let cipherText = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(jsonSerializedOrder, 'utf8'), cipher.final()]);
console.log('cipherText'+cipherText);
// Compute the HMAC
let hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', authenticationKey).update(Buffer.concat([iv, cipherText])).digest();
console.log('hmac'+hmac);
// Base64 encode the IV + cipherText + HMAC
let base64Payload = Buffer.concat([iv, cipherText, hmac]).toString("base64");
console.log('base64Payload'+base64Payload);
// URL encode to get the final payload
let payload = encodeURIComponent(base64Payload);


console.log(payload);
```

Comment: You said you can't use NodeJS -- can you explain where this code is going to be running (in the browser, on a server), and the environment? I'm not 100% clear on what you're asking. It seems like "Port this code sample to ... something"?

Comment: It will be running on the server side. Yeah, I am thinking like anything equivalent using OpenSSL or using simple crypto-JS(Browser version but I will execute on the server machine)

Comment: for more info, I am trying to implement https://support.trustpilot.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004145087--Business-Generated-Links-for-developers-